# play framework use in memory h2 database for unit tests

Tags: java, mysql, database, junit, playframework

I am trying to configure my play framework application so that it uses a mysql database when running and a in memory database for the tests.
When I run the tests it connects to the mysql database and not the in memory database.
Anyone know why?

This is my config:

```
db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/communityRoots?characterEncoding=UTF-8"
db.default.user=root
db.default.password= ""

db.test.driver=org.h2.Driver
db.test.url="jdbc:h2:mem:play;MODE=MYSQL"
db.test.user=sa
db.test.password=""
```

this is my test:

```
running(fakeApplication(inMemoryDatabase("test")), new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new User("bob@gmail.com", "Bob", "secret").save();
            assertNotNull(User.authenticate("bob@gmail.com", "secret"));
            assertNull(User.authenticate("bob@gmail.com", "badpassword"));
            assertNull(User.authenticate("tom@gmail.com", "secret"));
        }
    });
```

Comment: Another good approach would be to use h2 for DEV and TEST in application.conf, an to to use MySQL in production mode only with a separated application-prod.conf file

Comment: Yeah, I think that will be the solution ill go with. Was hoping there was a simpler/ cleaner way to do it. Thanks

Comment: As a side note: I use MariaDB4j as embedded database for testing. It's a real MySQL compatible database instead of the incomplete MySQL mode of H2. https://github.com/vorburger/MariaDB4j

Comment: @Ciaran0  how did you get this to work finally ?

Answer (score 1):

From an actual application I'm developing:

```
import play.api.inject.bind
import org.scalatest.mock.MockitoSugar
import play.api.Application
import play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationBuilder
import database.AccountDAO
import play.api.Configuration
import play.api.Mode


class AccountDAOSpec extends Specification with MockitoSugar { // we add mockito to show that you can also bind your mocks


val companyAccountDAOMock = mock[CompanyAccountDAO] // let us create a company account DAO mock

  def app = new GuiceApplicationBuilder() // you create your app
    .configure(
      Configuration.from(
        Map( // a custom configuration for your tests only
          "slick.dbs.default.driver" -> "slick.driver.H2Driver$",
          "slick.dbs.default.db.driver" -> "org.h2.Driver",
          "slick.dbs.default.db.connectionPool" -> "disabled",
          "slick.dbs.default.db.keepAliveConnection" -> "true",
          "slick.dbs.default.db.url" -> "jdbc:h2:mem:test",
          "slick.dbs.default.db.user" -> "sa",
          "slick.dbs.default.db.password" -> "")))
    .bindings(bind[AccountDAO].to[AccountDAOImpl]) // here you can define your bindings for an actual implementation (note the use of square brackets)
    .bindings(bind[CompanyAccountDAO].to(companyAccountDAOMock)) // or bind to your mock (note the use of parentheses)
    .in(Mode.Test)
    .build()


  "AccountDAO" should {

    "throw an Exception when adding a user with an invalid data" in new WithApplication(app) { // here you can use the application you just created, it uses the db you defined for your tests

      val app2dao = Application.instanceCache[AccountDAO]
      val accountDAO = app2dao(app) // with this you get the DAO injected

      accountDAO.addAccount(testAccount).run must throwAn[Exception] 
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should remove "test".
Thus your first line should be:

```
running(fakeApplication(inMemoryDatabase()), new Runnable() { 
    //test specific code
});
```